# HTML Select Element's hitbox isn't accurate

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an HTML `select` element with some custom styling on it. There's a region in the inner-right of the `select` that won't let you click/tap to activate the dropdown, despite the `width` and everything is correct.

[image]
*(I am hovering over the `select#` element here, not a container)*
Whenever I hover over the right region of the element, the `select` element loses hover focus, and its parent is targeted instead.

It's not the drop-down arrow icon, because its width is tiny

[image]
and when removed it makes no difference.

What's weird is that this issue appears on mobile devices and Google Chrome (when emulating a mobile device, using taps instead of clicks). When I use Firefox (which doesn't emulate a mobile device, but rather just changes the width/height of the page), everything works fine:
[image]

So using a touchscreen device (or simulating one) creates this issue, whereas using a traditional cursor works fine. Is there some difference between a `select` elements 'hitbox' on the touchscreen that might create this problem?

[CodeSandbox](https://jhrkh7.csb.app/)
*View using Chrome DevTools (or some other mobile device) with a mobile device preset to see the issue*

**Edit**: After some testing, the issue still occurs on android, even if you hook up a mouse. The pointer changes are working, but it still cuts off at a weird place:
[image]
Same thing on Chrome, the same thing on Edge. Firefox is the only browser that works fine. Even the Firefox Mobile app on Android works perfectly.
I haven't tested Safari.

Here's the CSS that is acting on the select element:

```
width: 200px;
display: block;
height: min-content;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 5px 15px;
border-radius: 18px;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease, max-height 0.5s ease;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden;
user-select: none;
position: relative;
border: none;
appearance: none;
```

*src/global/JForm/JForm.css .JForm__menustyle*

Comment: Please add the relevant code here rather than lots of graphics which do not particularly help

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Added. I believe the issue has something to do with Chromium

Comment: What happens if you remove `user-select`?

Comment: @morganney removing `user-select` doesn't fix the issue, I added that to prevent accidentally selecting the text on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For class names `scale-menu__row__JSelectContainer-scale` and `scale-menu__row__JSelectContainer-mode`,
You have assigned the style **`scale: 150%;`**.

That's what causing the issue. It is rendering button 50% larger than it actually is. That's why the select container is going beyond the boundries.

Let me know if this helps!

Edit:

You can remove `scale: 150%;` and add `position:relative;` on same class, to maintain the position of svg triangle icon

Comment: That's the correct answer, as using `scale` doesn't recalculate the actual size, just makes it bigger overflowing the content, creating issues as mentioned in the question.

Comment: That was it! Guess I gotta figure out a better way to make those buttons bigger. I was told there would be issues using scale but didn't listen to the warnings and forgot...
Odd that it was only an issue in Chromium-based browsers. That's the curse of JavaScript- you can't predict the compiler